# Are there tools for building CGPaths? (either in XCode/Swift or other)

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, cgpath

I'd like to make SKSpriteNodes to move along letter outlines. I have many letters but here's one example:

[image]

I would like the sprite to follow the red line.

I know this can be accomplished by creating appropriate CGPaths for each letter but I have many letters and creating paths for all of them is quite a job. Especially letters like P are bit of a work.

Is there a way to draw the CGPaths with someother software, Photoshop for example, and then just feed the coordinate points into Swift? Or is there a way to get the CGPaths from a picture like the A above?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at an application called PaintCode. I haven't used it, but I understand that it lets you use drawing tools and generates source code to recreate the drawing.